# How to know when delayed_job has done its job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping, delayed-job

I currently have a method in my model to scrape a site and insert records to a database.

```
def self.scrape
  #scrape
  #insert into database
end
```

I set up a controller method to call it:

```
def scrape
  Website.send_later(:scrape)
end
```

The scraping is working and have tested it by running it through the console. However, running it by activating it through calling the controller method it didn't work.

I've tried `rake jobs:work` it says the following:

```
[Worker(host:thorpe-desktop pid:6962)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:thorpe-desktop pid:6962)] Class#scrape completed after 0.5068
[Worker(host:thorpe-desktop pid:6962)] 1 jobs processed at 0.5898 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

I don't see anything in the database table where it should have inserted data.

Answer (score 2):

As a way to figure out if a job has run and completed you can use the hooks provided by delayed_job to write a small record to a job_status model. there are a few hooks that might be useful in this case and most interesting is:

```
def after(job)
  record_stat 'newsletter_job/after'
end
```

There are similar ones for success and finish that you could use similarly. I realize this might be heavier than you desire but it would do what you want and may be worth the cost. The delayed_job table doesn't seem to hold enough information as is for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This question [polling with delayed_job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582017/polling-with-delayed-job) has a good description of how to track when delayed jobs have finished or not.